# What is vector-map?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I was given a code by a teacher at my uni and I'm trying to understand this line of code:

```
(define printStatev (lambda (st)
                 (vector-map (lambda (row) (printRow row)) st)))
```

What is vector-map?

Comment: From here http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2003/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_9.html
"procedure+: vector-map procedure vector
    Procedure must be a procedure of one argument. vector-map applies procedure element-wise to the elements of vector and returns a newly allocated vector of the results, in order from left to right. The dynamic order in which procedure is applied to the elements of vector is unspecified. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector-map` applies a function to each element of a vector.

```
(vector-map - (vector 1 2 3))
```

calculates

```
(vector (- 1) (- 2) (- 3))
```

and the final result is

```
(vector -1 -2 -3)
```

In your example the function to apply is printRow. Since printRow as a side effect print the value (this is an assumption) the effect is that all elements are printed. The result value is a vector whose elements are the values returned from printRow.